# What does "Build and Release" in Jira versions mean?

Tags: jira

At project > settings > versions you can create versions and apply `Build and Release` on a version. I totally understand what `Release` means here (it applies a release date and sets the state to `released`), but what does `Build` mean here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an excerpt from [official JIRA documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/deploying-a-release-764478183.html#Deployingarelease-Buildtherelease):

> **Build the release.**
>   The next step is to build the release. A release is essentially a snapshot of the artifact(s) and related metadata that will be deployed. A release is created from a single build.
>   If you have connected JIRA Software to Bamboo, you can automatically run a Bamboo build when you release a version. Otherwise, if you haven't connected JIRA Software to Bamboo, or you are using a different build tool, you will need to run your builds independently.

So, primary purpose of the `build` option is to automatically run Bamboo build if Bamboo and JIRA are connected.

Comment: haven't managed to find it on my own, it seems. or i wasn't patient enough, sorry :o